# Is there a way to save ipycytoscape (javascript based object) in jupyter notebook(python)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipycytoscape

I was creating a graph through `ipycytoscape` https://ipycytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I have created an interactive graph through the package, in `jupyter notebook` with my python code. 
However, is there a way to save this javascript originated graph as an image?

below is an example code.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.complete_graph(5)
cyto = ipycytoscape.CytoscapeWidget()
cyto.graph.add_graph_from_networkx(G)
display(cyto)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the question.
I found something that might be a start for you: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html#Extracting-Figures-using-the-HTML-Exporter
If you wanna keep discussing this I'd recommend to open an issue in our github https://github.com/QuantStack/ipycytoscape/issues
Cheers!